# How to make count of similar data in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tmp`.

Query:

```
select * from tmp
```

[image]

I want the result in following way:

```
customer_id | subscriber_id  | totalSubscribers    
320         | 433            |     3  
320         | 434            |     3
```

Can you tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, with `COUNT`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for you question

```
SELECT customer_id , subscriber_id , count(*) AS totalSubscribers 
FROM `tmp` GROUP BY 1,2
```

or

```
SELECT customer_id , subscriber_id , count(*) AS totalSubscribers 
FROM `tmp` GROUP BY customer_id , subscriber_id
```

Here is screnshot for executed query 
[image]

Comment: Warning, your current method seem to be bugged: 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TABLE tmp( customer_id integer,  subscriber_id);

  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1,2);
  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (2,1);
  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (3,1);

SELECT customer_id , subscriber_id , count(*) AS totalSubscribers 
FROM `tmp` GROUP BY 1,2  >>> result: everybody has 1 totalSubscribers, despite nr2 should have 2 subscribers.

Comment: there is no bugs in my query. You inserting in table 3 different customers (with id 1, 2 and 3). And each of customers has only one subsriber )

Comment: customer 1 has 2 subscribers (2 and 3), customer 2 has 1 subscriber (customer 1), and customer 3 has 0 subscribers. but your code say everybody has 1 subscriber.

Comment: @hanshenrik you are wrong. According to your insert query: customer 1 has 1 subscriber with id=2, customer 2 has 1 subscriber with id=1 and customer 3 has 1 subscriber with id=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
  SELECT customer_id , subscriber_id , count(*) as [TOTAL]
    FROM  tmp
    GROUP BY customer_id , subscriber_id
```

Comment: does this really work though? doubt it

Comment: @KLin really? seems bugged to me: try the code here https://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
CREATE TABLE tmp( customer_id integer,  subscriber_id);

  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (1,2);
  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (2,1);
  INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (3,1);

  SELECT customer_id , subscriber_id , count(*) as [TOTAL]
    FROM  tmp
    GROUP BY customer_id , subscriber_id

Comment: @hanshenrik You inserting in table 3 different customers (with id 1, 2 and 3). And each of customers has only one subsriber )